# How to implement Postman OAuth token and secret retrieval in Python?

Tags: python, oauth

New to Python and don't know how to implement all the steps I am building in Postman.
The steps in  Postman are:
Get OAuth Token for KeyVault
Get: Get Secret from Vault
Post: Get OAuth Token for Graph SPO
Get: Get SiteUsage Detail
Get: Get SiteUsage Detail Daily
Get: Get SiteUsage File Count
Get: Get SiteUsage Site Count
Get: Get SiteUsage Storage
Get: Get SiteUsage Page
Get: Get SiteActivity Detail
Get: Get SiteActivity File Counts
Get: Get SiteActivity User Counts
Get: Get SiteActivity Pages

All these steps works fine in Postman.

I have implemented the above steps in Postman and works fine  but don't know how to do it in Python.